# Trying to understand monoids in Set as general monoid in monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

- In [the definition of a monoid in monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)), unit is defined as η: I → M, such that the following graph commutes.

[image]

- While in [the definition of a monoid in **Set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), unit of a set $S$ is defined as an element $e \in S$, such that
  $\forall a \in S, e \cdot a = a = a \cdot e$

I would like to know:

1. How these two definitions corresponds to each other.
2. I know that $\otimes$ means the bifunctor in the definition of a monoidal category, thus $I \otimes M$, $M \otimes M$, etc. are all objects in that monoidal category. But what does $\eta \otimes 1$ on the arrow mean? Since $\eta$ is a morphism instead of an object in the monoidal category, I cannot come up with an explanation of its meaning.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1: In $\mathsf{Set}$, the monoidal product $\otimes$ is actually the Cartesian product $\times$ of sets, and $I$, the unit object, is some one-element set $1 = \{*\}$. Then if $M$ is a monoid, $\mu : M \times M \to M$ is the monoid multiplication, $\eta: 1 \to M$ is the function that sends $*$ to the unit element  $e \in M$. The functions $\lambda,\rho$ give the obvious isomorphisms $M \times 1 \cong M \cong 1 \times M$. The first triangle says that $\lambda(*,m) = \mu(\eta(*),\mathrm{id}_{M}(m))$. Just filling in definitions, this gives $m = e \cdot m$. The other triangle similarly gives $m = m \cdot e$.

For 2: A bi-endofunctor on $\mathsf C$ is really just a functor $\otimes: \mathsf C \times \mathsf C \to \mathsf C$. In particular, it should take morphisms of $\mathsf C \times \mathsf C$ to morphisms of $\mathsf C$. Morphisms of $\mathsf C \times \mathsf C$ from $(X,X')$ to $(Y,Y')$ are pairs of morphisms $(f,f')$ where $f: X \to Y$ and $f': X'\to Y'$. Typically, we write $\otimes(f,f')$ as $f \otimes f'$. Thus, $\eta \otimes 1$ is the image of $(\eta,1)$ under the functor $\otimes$. Note that $1$ here refers to $\mathrm{id}_M$.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused about the meaning of $\eta:1->M$, what does it mean to "send * to the unit element $e \in M$? I can understand $\mu$ corresponds to multiplication in **Set**, since mutiplication can also be seen as a mapping. But how can $\eta$(a mapping) corresponds to the concept of e? Thank you!

Comment: Recall $1 = \{*\}$, a one-element set. Then $\eta: 1 \to M$ is defined by $\eta(*) = e$. Specifying an element of a set is the same as giving a mapping from $1$ into that set.

Comment: I see, thanks. Another question is that: Since $\eta \otimes 1$ is the image of $(\eta, 1)$ under functor $\otimes$, then what's image? It seems that you assumed that $(\otimes(\eta, 1))(\otimes(x, y)) = \otimes(\eta(x), 1(y))$, why does this happen? is there any condition ensuring this? Thanks!

Comment: A priori, $\otimes(x,y)$ does not mean anything. In the particular case of $\mathsf{Set}$, we have that $\otimes = \times$, and $1 \times \eta$ is the mapping $1 \times M \to M \times M$ that sends $(*,m)$ to $(e,m)$. I.e., it is $\eta$ on the first coordinate and $\id_M$ on the second. This is just the definition of $\times$ as a bifunctor.

Comment: That's weird, because from wikipedia, $\otimes$ in **Set** is just a Cartesian product, but it does not talk anything about how $\otimes$ works on morphisms. Thus I really wonder where I can know this "hidden" definition of $\otimes$ that $otimes(f1, f2)$ in **Set** means f1 on the first coordinate and f2 on the second?  Moreover, In other places, I also often see description of a monoidal category where its $\otimes$ is just (partially?) defined as mapping on objects instead of both on objects and morphisms. Thus I was thinking that there might be some conditions restricting the..(cont'd)

Comment: definition of functor $\otimes$ on morphisms (say $\otimes(f1, f2) (\otimes(x, y)) = \otimes(f1(x), f2(y))$, i.e. first function on first coordinate, second function on second coordinate), isn't there?

Comment: Often, it is clear from context what a functor should do on morphisms. If a functor is given functions $f: X \to Y$ and $f ': X' \to Y'$, then there is really only one function $X \times X' \to Y \times Y'$ you can make from that. When it is clear from context, the precise definition is often omitted. This is sloppy, but in the long run it gets tedious to explicitly specify obvious things every time, so we abbreviate.

Comment: Sorry I msread your comment, what I meant is that given $f: X -> Y$ and $f': X'->Y'$, then $(f \otimes f')(X \otimes Y) = f(X) \otimes f(Y)$( where X, Y are objects, f and f' are morphisms) holds true for all cases?

Comment: That doesn't make sense -- $f \otimes f'$ is just a morphism, it doesn't take an object like $X \otimes Y$ as an argument. In general, objects of categories don't have elements the way sets do, so $f \otimes f'$ need not even be a function. I recommend you carefully work through some examples of monoidal categories yourself to get a little more feeling for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45976/discussion-between-lifu-huang-and-mees-de-vries).